# How to prove that the second condition for Leibniz test is met for the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

So, here is the series: $\sum^{\infty}_{2}\frac{k}{(k\ln x +x^2)^2}$. I need to show that $\frac{k+1}{((k+1)\ln x +x^2)^2}  - \frac{k}{(k\ln x +x^2)^2} \ge 0 \ \ \ \forall x\in (0, \infty), \forall k \ge 2 $

How to do that?

Comment: As written, the series diverges for all $x$.  Was this supposed to be an alternating series?  If so, for any fixed $x>0$, the alternating version of this series will eventually (i.e., for $k$ large enough) will satisfy the conditions for application of Leibniz's test.  If you want to show this directly, treat $k$ as a continuous variable, differentiate the absolute value of the general terms with respect to $k$, and show that the derivative will be positive for all $k$ beyond some value of $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

As written, the series diverges for all $x$.  We shall assume that the series of interest is $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k k}{(k\log(x)+x^2)^2}$.

Then, we can write the positive part of the general terms of the alternating series as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{k}{(k\log(x)+x^2)^2}&=\frac1{\log(x)}\left(\frac{k\log(x)+x^2-x^2}{(k\log(x)+x^2)^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{\log(x)}\left(\frac1{k\log(x)+x^2}-\frac{x^2}{(k\log(x)+x^2)^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Note that we have split the original series into the difference of two series, both of which have positive parts that are monotonically decreasing by inspection.

Can you finish now?

Comment: No, I am not sure what was the reason you manipulated the series the way you did.

Comment: I've edited to provide more guidance. Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't check my account since I asked the question.